# How to get 8 bit Colors?

Tags: java, colors, 8-bit

So ,at this moment, I got a method which generates 3 random integers, from 0 to 255.

I use the 3 integers for colors.Red, Green ,Blue.

So,at this moment, if I want to set the color of something, with the generated colors, I use this:

```
 Color.argb(255, r, g, b); //255 =max intensity and after ,there are red green blue
```

What I need to do ,is to convert the 3 integers ,or eventually the intensity value too, to a 8bit integer.

Any sort of documentation or guidance is highly appreciated!

If more information is needed, I will comment or modify the body of the question.

Comment: hava a look here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775442/relative-8-bit-color-of-a-16-bit-conversion

Comment: To put 24 bits of data in 8 bits of space you will loose information.  Some systems use a palette (a lookup table of colours) to get as close as they can to the original (gifs can do this).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801366/convert-rgb-values-into-integer-pixel

Comment: Using 8-bit will lose some data about the color anyway. That's the "beauty" of the 64 colors which you can get.

Comment: Yea, I know about this...but my employer wants 8 bits...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can encode the colors the following way:

```
Bits    0### 1### 2### 3### 4### 5### 6### 7###
        Alpha---- Red------ Green---- Blue-----
```

Note that you'll lose a whole lot of information about the color (but I think that's the thing you want to get).

Things you'll need to do in order to encode:

- Change the range of colors (`0-255` to `0-3`)
- Shift the colors properly and add them to get the 8bit value.

Here's some example code:

```
import java.awt.Color;

abstract class EightBit {
  public static int fromColor(Color c) {
    return ((c.getAlpha() >> 6) << 6)
         + ((c.getRed()   >> 6) << 4)
         + ((c.getGreen() >> 6) << 2)
         +  (c.getBlue()  >> 6);
  }
  public static Color toColor(int i) {
    return new Color(((i >> 4) % 4) * 64,
                     ((i >> 2) % 4) * 64,
                      (i       % 4) * 64,
                      (i >> 6)      * 64);
  }
}
```

### Explanation

#### Encoding

Let's start with an example color: `new Color(200, 59, 148, 72)`. Now we'll convert that into an integer. The binary representation of the color is:

```
Alpha 200 -- 11001000
Red    59 -- 00111011
Green 148 -- 10010100
Blue   72 -- 01001000
```

Now, we shift them to the right by 6 bits (so we get the first 2 bits):

```
Alpha 3 -- 11
Red   0 -- 00
Green 2 -- 10
Blue  1 -- 01
```

Now we put them together:

```
Bits  [ 1 ][ 1 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 1 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 1 ] -- 209
       ALPHA---  RED-----  GREEN---  BLUE----
```

It's `209`. See?

#### Decoding

So we're back at our 8bit number: `209`. We want to decode it. First, we need to get the 2-bit colors back by shifting them to the right, and modulo 4:

```
Bits  [ 1 ][ 1 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 1 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 1 ]
      \_shift_by_6_bits_____________[ 1 ][ 1 ] -- 3 (Alpha)
                \_by_4_bits_________[ 0 ][ 0 ] -- 0 (Red)
                          \_by_2____[ 1 ][ 0 ] -- 2 (Green)
                   shift by 0 bits: [ 0 ][ 1 ] -- 1 (Blue)
```

Now we multiply them by 64:

```
3 * 64 = 192 (Alpha)
0 * 64 =   0 (Red)
2 * 64 = 128 (Green)
1 * 64 =  64 (Blue)
```

And put them back into a `Color` object. As you can see, the colors are different: some information about the color was lost in the process. This is called [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression).

Comment: Would you please explain me the whole process?

I am pretty sure I understand how it works, but I want to make sure I don't use misunderstood concepts.

Anyways, overall it looks like what I need.

Going to test it right away and check the answer if everything is right.

 (Gonna give you an up too, as long as you explain what you have done,a bit)

Comment: Explanation is done! Make sure to accept the answer (with its exhaustive explanation).